# Exploring dissimilar research topics

Tags: career-path, early-career, research-topic, reputation, interdisciplinary

I'm currently a graduate student, but I plan on my future career being in research and academia. I like many different related topics and I like being interdisciplinary in my topics, and I see myself changing topics and doing my research broadly. However, professors usually stick to one topic for a very long time (either their entire lives or some absurd length like eight years) and milk every subtopic within it. I cannot see myself doing that willingly, but I also hear that staying within one topic allows you to essentially "master" it, thus getting you a better reputation, which feeds into a positive cycle of more publications, conference invites, security, etc. How true is that? Could I switch between topics and expect to be fine?

Answer (score 3):

Eight years is not an "absurd amount of time" to work on a single topic by any measure: one-year research projects are typically exploratory in nature, one could expect to knock off some low-hanging fruit but that is about it. For most projects, three to five years is a more typical research cycle, and committing this much is to be expected. Eight years is just a couple of projects done in a single field.

Now, there are options for making more frequent changes. The easiest one is assuming an instrumentalist role, mastering a set of techniques and doing projects from varying fields. It requires a lot of commitment to said set of techniques, but you can get to work on a wide variety of research. Say, if you run a lab with an advanced microscope, material scientists and biologists of all kinds might want to enter a collaboration. If you run a ML lab, you get an even wider variety of projects.

Be aware, however, that with this approach you would be limited to a certain role; you might make suggestions regarding the experiment design and refine your technique, but not much more than that.

And for theoretical research, one still has to draw from being a sufficiently good *specialist* in a number of fields to be able to be a *generalist* at all. Research questions often defy classification - the notion of a field in research is no more than a useful tool, and nothing prevents anyone from applying e.g. [differential geometry in number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063917/how-important-is-differential-geometry-for-number-theory). The reason we stick to these fields is that a lot of effort is otherwise spent on learning the basics: from experience, it typically takes no less than an year to just get up to speed and start generating ideas people have already published a few years ago as opposed to decades ago.

The romanticized idea of polymath geniuses who just go about and solve a bunch of open problems in all the different fields is almost entirely unrealistic. In older times, a select few could even afford to do science; now we have many bright minds working in every field imaginable. Unlike industry, academia does not care much about whether you are the best baker in town: if someone across the world has strictly better results, yours are irrelevant. To be a successful generalist in science, you still have to be good at *something*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but do you think the idea of learning the basics still applies in social sciences and humanities as those are all interrelated and do not have the distinct prior knowledge need of, say, physics and biology, as they are mostly interrelated. Going off of this, my goal is not to be a polymath, but because I have a genuine interest in doing research I find it hard to limit myself to one field, and see myself wanting to study psychology (my specialization, which in itself is further divided) but also study poli sci, cultural studies, linguistics, and education.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I do not know much about humanities, but I believe most of the answer should still apply: you may bring your tools and expertise from psychology and use them in poli sci or cultural studies. Day-to-day work in this case could probably be described as "using psychology in the context of ...", the change of the field is a bit superficial then, and I cover it in the "often defy classification" section. But if you would need a complete retooling, it then becomes unreasonable to expect external funding, thus most researchers do not do that.